# How can a collection of instances be sorted by Type from least to most dependent based on property relationships?

Tags: c#

If I have the following classes with the certain properties. How can I create a method to sort them by their property dependency? Please see the comment in the code to see the expected result.

```cs
class One { }

class Two {
    One A { get; set; }
}

class Three {
    One A { get; set; }
    Four D { get; set; }
}

class Four {
    Two B { get; set; }
}

class Five {
    Six F { get; set; }
}

class Six {
    One A { get; set; }
    Five E { get; set; }
}

class Seven {
    Five E { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var collection = [
        new Six(),
        new Three(),
        new Seven(),
        new One(),
        new Five(),
        new Two(),
        new Four()
    ];

    var dependentCollection = BuildCollectionByPropertyDependance(collection);

    // dependentCollection => [
    //   [ One ],
    //   [ Two, Six, Five ],
    //   [ Four, Seven ],
    //   [ Three ]
    // ]
  }

  // public ... BuildCollectionByPropertyDependance() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Use reflection: `GetProperties().Count`?

Comment: So you want a Topological Sort but you also want to allow cycles (Five<-->Six) and have then flattened to the same level in the result? Also, is your question how to build the dependency graph using reflection or how to generate an order from the graph once you've obtained it?

Comment: @IanMercer Correct. How to generate an order.

Comment: So a *Topological Sort* would be the normal technique but with a cycle that can't work because you don't know where to start. Instead consider algorithms like *PageRank* that can order a graph based on dependencies between nodes when cycles are present.

Comment: @Johnathan Barckay: 'GetProperties()' would only return public properties,not internal ones. For a complete list of properties use 'GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)'

Answer (score 0):

You would need to determine the inheritance/dependency relationship between the classes and the relations between them (in your case properties), you could use this to generate a tree/graph-like structure of the classes, and determine the root node. Then you could use the tree depth of each node to sort the list, or just do a Breadth First Search/Traversal (BFS) of the inheritance tree which will naturally create the kind of ordered list you are looking for.

That approach will work across any inheritance/dependency structure.

Could you provide more details about your sorting logic? It's not entirely clear from your post. The approach I described is fairly generic, but I think it should work for you.

However, as a comment mentioned, `Properties.Count` could get you most of the way there, but if a subclasses that don't add any properties could be sorted in correctly.

Comment: Probably not a tree, so Topological Sort might be more appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, I re-read the question, and I realized he was asking about the property relationships, not just subclass relationships. I think the rough strategy will work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean simply the number of properties:

```
IEnumerable<object[]> BuildCollectionByPropertyDependance(object[] objects)
{
    return objects
        .GroupBy(o => o.GetType().GetProperties().Count)
        .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
        .Select(grp => grp.ToArray());
}
```

Or if you mean recursively, something like the following:

```
IEnumerable<object[]> BuildCollectionByPropertyDependance(object[] objects)
{
    return objects
        .GroupBy(o => CountNestedProperties(o.GetType()))
        .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
        .Select(grp => grp.ToArray());
}

int CountNestedProperties(Type type, IList<Type> checked = null)
{
    checked = checked ?? new List<Type>();

    if (checked.Contains(type))
    {
       return 0;
    }

    if (type.IsPrimitive)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    checked.Add(type);

    return 1 + type.GetProperties().Sum(prop => CountNestedProperties(prop.PropertyType, checked));
}
```

Comment: Good except ... `Five` ... `Six` ... `Five` ... `Six` ... `StackOverflow`.

Comment: Ye, didn't think about circular reference. Just amended.